# Get description of other job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

is there a way to using groovy get description of other jenkins job than "currentBuild" ?
I was trying `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(<job_name>).lastBuild.getBuildVariables().get("Description");`
but it doesn't work. It always returns that `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(<job_name>)` is a null object.

What makes it harder is that job is in project (folder)

```
https://jenkins.xxx/job/FOLDERJOBS/job/JOB_TO_BE_EXTRACTED
```

Thanks

Comment: want to understand the context here for using the description or any variable of the other job? What's the purpose?

Comment: I have to update description of job "A" from level of job "B". Depends on with what status job "B" finish.

Comment: Could you please help me understand why do we want to update the description of a parent job based on job B status?

Comment: Just because project require such functionality. It doesn't matter  why,  let's say just to store information in job A, how jobs B ends.

Comment: [getItemByFullName(fullName)](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getItemByFullName-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-), where `fullName=FOLDERJOBS//JOB_TO_BE_EXTRACTED`. GetItem only works at root level, not folder compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName()`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getItemByFullName-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) instead of [`getItem()`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getItemByFullName-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-).

That method works with full job names (including folders), like `FOLDERJOBS/JOB_TO_BE_EXTRACTED`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in my script console and it works. Could you please try this?

```
text="New Descritption" 
def jobName = "test/test1".split("/")
def it=Jenkins.instance
for(name in jobName){
   it=it.getItem(name)
}
it.description = text
```

You may need to approve few methods(whitelist) in Manage Jenkins to probably make it work in case it gives you permission error.